# Is that possible to access the cam and mic of remote user in video chat using actionscript3.?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am working on actionscript3.
Here i am using the av-chat module for video chat.i add up the recording functionality in it.Now i also want to record the remote user video in it.
Is that possibility in Action script to Access the cam and mic of remote user.??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes.  Consider a web search on matter.  I'm feeling lucky google search:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d49.html

At Stackoveflow, a good question shows what you've tried and your current code.  for future questions, put more effort into showing you've tried to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Camera.get()` or `Microphone.get()` methods, Flash Player displays a Privacy dialog box, in which the user can allow or deny access to their camera and microphone. I hope it will work.